How to filter included records in a Prisma computed field
In Prisma, I know we can filter with where the records that we include in a certain .findMany request as specified in the doc:
const result = await prisma.user.findMany({
  // ...
  include: {
    posts: {
      where: {
        published: true,
      },
    },
  },
})

I would like to do the same, but in a computed field. I created a computed field for a batch model that returns the amount of disposals done for a certain batch ( batch 1--N disposals ) in the past 7 days.
I would like the following code to work:
type BatchExtended = {
  id?: string;
  startDate?: Date;
  endDate?: Date;
  disposals?: Disposal[];
};

prisma = new PrismaClient().$extends({
  result: {
    batch: {
      lastWeekDisposals: {
        include: {
          disposals: {
            where: {
              createdAt: {
                gte: add(new Date(), { weeks: -1 }),
                lte: new Date(),
              },
            }
          }
        },
        compute(batch: BatchExtended) {
          return batch.disposals.length;
        },
      },
    },
  },
});

Unfortunately, despite the fact the above code doesn't break, it doesn't filter the disposals either and return all the disposal records, not just the past 7 days ones.
(note: in the code add is from date-fns).
The workaround code I have is the following. It works perfectly, but I expect its performance to be quite bad vs filtering within the prisma query:
prisma = new PrismaClient().$extends({
  result: {
    batch: {
      lastWeekDisposals: {
        include: {
          disposals: true,
        },
        compute(batch: BatchExtended) {
          return batch.disposals.filter(
            (disp) =>
              disp.createdAt >= add(new Date(), { weeks: -1 }) &&
              disp.createdAt < new Date(),
          ).length;
        },
      },

    },
  },
});

Do you have a more elegant and better performance solution? Or a different approach to that problem?
